# How to Hide highcharts series name on the chart in Android Studio?

Tags: android

In the question [Hide highcharts series name on the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822274/hide-highcharts-series-name-on-the-chart)
The method that Deep 3015 proposed to hide the series name on the chart was successfully used:

> remove https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js">

And this method works great for me. But I can’t find how to use such a method in Android Studio, I couldn’t find the option to disable the series-label.js module
Does anyone know how to do this or another way to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really turned out to be very simple. I was hit by the fact that I have area type charts, and there the labels look different, they are under the chart and I thought that they are controlled by another parameter ...
In addition, I read the data from the csv file, and I had to prohibit labels for each series separately:

```
HIOptions hiOptions = new HIOptions ();
HIArea area = new HIArea ();
HIArea area1 = new HIArea ();
HILabel label = new HILabel ();
label.setEnabled (false);
area.setLabel (label);
area1.setLabel (label);

ArrayList nAreas = new ArrayList <HISeries> ();
nAreas.add (area);
nAreas.add (area1);
hiOptions.setSeries (nAreas);
```